# Is there a "while...else" in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have a hash with cat names for keys and cat instances for values. Is there a way to make it so that when people type a `response` that isn't in a key in the `cats` hash for the terminal to reprint the `puts "Which cat would you like to know about?"` question or type: "Try again"? I guess I'm asking for sort of a "while... else".

```
puts "Which cat would you like to know about?"
puts cats.keys
response = gets.chomp

while cats.include?(response)
  puts "The cat you chose is #{cats[response].age} old"
  puts "The cat you chose is named #{cats[response].name}"
  puts "The cat you chose is a #{cats[response].breed} cat"
  puts "Is there another cat would you like to know about?"
  response = gets.chomp
end
```

Comment: Th answer is **no**. Probably you need to wrap the body of the `while` in an `if`, or something like that.

Comment: You have an ungrammatical sentence `Is there ...` in puts.

Comment: `while...else` is something Python has that I wish Ruby had as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a "while...else", as far as I know. If you do not mind the loop continuing regardless of whether the response is a valid cat name or not, maybe this will work for you:

```
puts "Which cat would you like to know about?"
puts cats.keys

while true
  response = gets.chomp
  if response.empty?
    break
  elsif cats.include?(response)
    puts "The cat you chose is #{cats[response].age} old"
    puts "The cat you chose is named #{cats[response].name}"
    puts "The cat you chose is a #{cats[response].breed} cat"
    puts "Is there another cat would you like to know about?"
  else
    puts "There is no cat with that name. Try again."
  end
end
```

This will repeatedly prompt the user for a cat name, until the user responds with an empty string, at which point it will break out of the loop.

Comment: Won't this loop forever regardless of the if result? Don't you need a break or something? (I don't know ruby)

Comment: @Tudor: That was indeed the case. I've added a break condition now. :-)

Comment: @Tudor Normally, you do need a break, but that is not what the OP wants.

Comment: +1. only answer so far to lay the logic clearly. You can advise the OP to do `cat = cats[response]` to DRY it a little bit. Or also `elsif (cat = cats[response])`.

Comment: you can also indent with 2 spaces, that's the idiomatic in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

You could rearrange your code with an additional question:

```
cats = {'a' => 1} #testdata
continue = true   #set a flag

while continue
  puts "Which cat would you like to know about?"
  response = gets.chomp
  while cats.include?(response)
    puts cats[response]
    puts "Is there another cat would you like to know about?"
    response = gets.chomp
  end
  puts "Try another? (Y for yes)"
  continue = gets.chomp =~ /[YyJj]/ #Test for Yes or yes, J for German J...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have played with Ruby, but something like this comes to mind:

```
def main
   print_header
       while true
           resp = get_response
           if cats.include?(resp)
              print_info(resp)
           else
              print_header
       end
end

def get_response
    puts cats.keys
    response = gets.chomp
end

def print_header
    puts "Which cat would you like to know about?"
end

def print_info response
  puts "The cat you chose is #{cats[response].age} old"
  puts "The cat you chose is named #{cats[response].name}"
  puts "The cat you chose is a #{cats[response].breed} cat"
  puts "Is there another cat would you like to know about?"
end
```

Please note that you will need a terminal point. If `get_response` returns "no", then quit.

Answer (score 0):

```
continuous = false
loop do
  unless continuous
    puts "Which cat would you like to know about?", cats.keys
  else
    puts "Is there another cat would you like to know about?"
  end
  if cat = cats[gets.chomp]
    puts "The cat you chose is #{cat.age} old"
    puts "The cat you chose is named #{cat.name}"
    puts "The cat you chose is a #{cat.breed} cat"
    continuous = true
  else
    continuous = false
  end
end
```

Comment: @DGM Changed to loop, following your comment.